# how to encode the "&" special character in any url..?

Tags: iphone

how to encode the "&" special character in any url..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL-encoded value for an ampersand is `%26`.

Answer (score 0):

its as said %26, more in here: http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm